# Analytic off the real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> If $f:\mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous and $f$ is analytic off the real axis, then show that $f$ is entire.

Comment: I tried using Morera's theorem but I can't seem to get it right

Comment: what do you mean by off?

Comment: @lee $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @lee as Brett said we know that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb C$\ $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous everywhere this should be enough to get that $f$ is entire i.e $f$ will be analytic on the real axis.

Answer (score 3):

By continuity, $f$ is bounded on $\{x+iy: -a\leq x\leq a, -\varepsilon \leq y \leq \varepsilon\}$.  Then by dominated convergence, $\lim_{y\to 0}\int_{-a}^af(x+iy)\ dx=\int_{-a}^af(x)\ dx$.

Now we can take the integral of $f$ on a cirlce of radius $a$ centered at $0$ as the limit of the integrals over two semi-circles, one in each half-plane, and apply Morera's theorem.

Comment: Can you please explain more, and why it's enough to consider circles only ?? Thanx

Comment: If you look at the proof of Morera's theorem, you'll see that circles suffice. But you could apply the argument above to any contour integral.

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem:**  (Symmetry principle) If $f^+$ and $f^−$ are holomorphic functions in $Ω^+$ and $Ω^−$ respectively, that extend continuously to I and 
>   $$f^+(x) = f^−(x)\quad for\;all\;x ∈ I,$$
>   then the function $f$ deﬁned on $Ω$ by 
>   $$f(z) = $$$$f^+ (z)\quad if\quad z ∈ Ω^+ ,\quad f^+(z) = f^−(z)\quad if\quad z ∈ I,\quad f^−(z)\quad if\quad  ∈ Ω^−$$
>   is holomorphic on all of $Ω$.(COMPLEX ANALYSIS Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi page 58)

According to the theorem you have $f^+=f^-=f$ , $Ω^+$ is upper half plain $Ω^-$ is lower half plain and $I=\mathbb{R}$ so $f$ is holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ means entire.